# Getting Embedded Charts in Google Spreadsheet Broken?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts, google-sheets

I've been running into the error 'Service error: Spreadsheets (line 55, file "Code")' when using the .getCharts() method on a sheet object.

I'm attempting to create a chart in google sheets through the API and then retrieve it back in the code as a proof of concept, and I still retrieve the error. I can verify that the chart has been created appropriately in the code block below, but the issue arises when using that .getCharts() method. Here's the code:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Plot");
  var chartBuilder = sheet.newChart();
  var inputRange = sheet.getRange("B2:B50");
  chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!').setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0).addRange(inputRange);
  sheet.insertChart(chartBuilder.build());
  var sheetID = sheet.getCharts()[0].getId();
  Logger.log(sheetID);
```

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason of your issue is that the chart is not created correctly. In your script, `inputRange` is not used for `chartBuilder`. So in this situation, the created chart has no data. By this, I think that such error occurs.

In order to avoid this, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!').setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0);
```

#### To:

```
chartBuilder.setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE).setOption('title', 'My Line Chart!').setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0).addRange(inputRange);
```

#### Note:

- Before you run the script, please remove the existing charts. Because in your script, `sheet.getCharts()[0]` is used and the chart of 1st index is retrieved.

#### References:

- [newChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#newchart)
- [Class EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder)
- [addRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#addrangerange)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: I had explored these possibilities before posting the question: Sorry I should have noted that. It still is producing the error, considering everything you mentioned.

Comment: @Jaden Ranzenberger Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I can confirm that your script works by above modification. I cannot replicate your issue. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm your issue. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "Service error: Spreadsheets" by enabling Flash plugin in my browser (Firefox). Dunno why, but it works.